# No I2c Slave Address for Communication

Tags: protocols

i am using I2C base sensor. But that sensor is not having address(slave). So can i communicate with it without address. It will send ack and data?.

Comment: It must have address. What is part number (model) of sensor?

Comment: MMA7660FC - 3axis ACCELEROMETER

Comment: Posted answer, please accept it if it answer you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `The Slave Address` chapter (p. 21, Figure 10, [MMA7660FC datasheet](http://www.freescale.com.cn/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA7660FC.pdf?fpsp=1)), MMA7660FC has fixed (hardwired) slave address which is normally 1001100 (0x4C). It could be changed to another in range (0x08 to 0xEF) by request to factory.

So, this is normal I2C device (with address), you could communicate with it using 0x4C slave address.

Well, if you unsure what address the sensor has, try to poll sensor with different addresses in a loop. Sensor must answer to one of addresses.

Comment: Thanks alexender, it's really helpful